# download remote image in codeigniter

Tags: image, codeigniter, download

I want to download a remotely hosted image using codeiogniter . and a validation feature also has to be added so that only images are downloaded..
is it possible to use the built in functions offered by CI ??

thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is not from CI but PHP, think it can be usefull anyway.
May be checking the image size is enough to be sure it's an image, like

```
$imagedata = getimagesize('http://othersite.com/image.jpg');
```

or use [exif_imagetype](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php)

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'exif_imagetype' ) ) {
    function exif_imagetype ( $filename ) {
        if ( ( list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize( $filename ) ) !== false ) {
            return $type;
        }
    return false;
    }
}


if( exif_imagetype('http://othersite.com/image.jpg') ) 
{  
//is an image 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To get a remote image, you can just use file_get_contents, assuming allow_url_fopen is set to on in php.ini.

```
$image=file_get_contents('http://othersite.com/image.jpg');
```

Once you have that, you can validate the file extension, or try and [resize the image](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html) to check that it really is an image.